# Error in OpenCV Android eclipse setting up sample projects

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I already watched so many tutorials online but I can't figure out what's wrong with the sample projects given by the openCv. [image]

I also follow the steps given in this link : [sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916545/build-errors-while-trying-to-set-up-opencv4android)

The error in 15 puzzle is different from camera-calibration and color-blob-detection.
[image] 
[image]
After I deleted the error lines in JavaCameraView.java file, some of the samples start to works fine.
[image] 
My ndk version is r10 and OpenCV version is 2.4.9. I hope someone can help me solve my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at this post [sample][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554119/opencv-android-sample-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some configurations, I finally figured out how to solve my problem. Here are the steps:

First: Click on every folder->Properties->Android->Delete the unknown reference then add the OpenCV library.[image]
Second: Make sure to link the C/C++ Build by Properties-> C/C++ Build-> Then copy the file path of your ndk folder[image]
Third:copy jni folder present in face detection or other projects then paste it to a project that don't have a jni folder.

Fourth: Change the include declaration to local library of OpenCV.mk in Android.mk file.

Ex. include C:/Dev/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk[image] 
Fifth:Make sure to clean and build the project.

Finally run every project on your device. cherio!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554119/opencv-android-sample-error?rq=1). Basically you will just need to redirect the library to your folder

Comment: Please refrain from adding link-only answers as they turn invalid when the link is removed. It is better to quote important parts of the article in your answer.